# how to convert nvarchar from T-SQL dialect to hiveQL?

Tags: string, t-sql, apache-spark, etl, hiveql

i'm doing ETL task of transforming queries from one SQL dialect to another. The old db uses T-Sql, the new is hiveQL.

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(FMH.FLUIDMODELID,'_',RESERVOIR,'_',PRESSUREPSIA) AS NVARCHAR(255)) AS FACT_RRFP_INJ_PRESS_R_PHK
, FMH.FluidModelID ,FMH.FluidModelName ,[AnalysisDate] 

    FROM dbo.LZ_RRFP_FluidModelInj fmi 
    LEFT JOIN DBO.LZ_RRFP_FluidModelHeader fmh ON fmi.FluidModelIDFK = fmh.FluidModelID
    LEFT JOIN LZ_RRFP_FluidModelAss fma on fma.InjectionFluidModelIDFK = fmi.FluidModelIDFK
WHERE FMA.RESERVOIR  IN (SELECT RESERVOIR_CD FROM ATT_RESERVOIR)
```

the error is :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
DataType nvarchar(255) is not supported.
```

how to convert nvarchar?

Comment: Why are you using CAST? If this SELECT statement is standalone then it's not achieving anything; if its part of a bigger statement such as an INSERT... SELECT then, if CAST is necessary, then cast to the target column type i.e.STRING

Answer (score 1):

Hive uses UTF-8 in STRINGs and VARCHARs, you are fine with using `VARCHAR` or `STRING` instead of `NVARCHAR`.

`VARCHAR` in Hive is the same as STRING + length validation. As @NickW mentioned in the comment, you can do the same without `CAST` at all, if you inserting result into the table with `VARCHAR(255)`, it will work the same without CAST.